# Appcomponent variables are undefined after loading webcam component

Tags: angular

Actually my problem is that I have an AppComponent with global variable, during the ngOnInit i assigning the values to global variables which is working fine for all other components am loading. But for the webCam Component once its open i capture the image and have send button after i click the send button it should go to the method of SendData() which supposed to give the global variable url to send the data, but this time the global variable are undefined ! why its happening ? especially for the webCam component only have this type of error.

I tried to assign the global variable to const variable on ngOnInit method, but it overrides also to undefined.

```
private url: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.url= 'some url';
}

// after click the send button in webcam component it call sendMessage()
public sendMessage(message: any) {

const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
console.log(message);
formdata.append('text', message);
formdata.append('data', new Blob([JSON.stringify(message)], { type:'application/json' }));

this.webService.makeRequest(this.url,  // here the url is undefined only for after webcam component
  'POST', formdata, null, 
  (res: any) => {
     console.log(res.status);
  }, 
  (err) => {
    this.console.log(err);
  });
```

}

// In webCamComponent.ts

```
 sendImage() {
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', new File([this.dataURItoBlob(this.webcamImage.imageAsBase64)], names, { type: 'image/jpeg' }));

const uploadUrl = 'https://10.3.3.3/fileUpload';

this.webService.makeRequest(uploadUrl,
  'POST', formData, null, (res: any) => {

    if(res.status==='success'){ 
      this.appComponent.sendMessage('IMAGE SUCCESS');
    }
  },
  (err) => { 
    this.loggerService.error(err);
    this.appComponent.sendMessage(err);
  }
  );
 this.dialogRef.close(formData);
}
```

// Expected

```
this.webService.makeRequest(this.url,  // I need the url which i assigned in ngOnInit(), for other component i can able to get url from this same method, only for webcam i cant get.
  'POST', formdata, null, 
  (res: any) => {
     console.log(res.status);
  }, 
  (err) => {
    this.console.log(err);
  });
```

}

Comment: Can you please add the piece of the code where you call sendMessage method?

Comment: I call the sendMessage method from the webCamComponent by injecting the appComponent via constructor.

Comment: That's ok, but please show us the code where you're actually referring `.sendMessage` method. The reason I'm asking is that that please can be more relevant to your issue

Comment: I added the code where i send the sendMessage(), pls check

Comment: I'm checking now and it looks good to me at first glance. And that's strange. Is there any chance you can replicate this issue on stackblitz with minimal required code?

Comment: NO, i post this issue stackoverflow only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m typescript you can

```
       export class MyClass{
       public static MY_URL: string = "Something";
       }
```

Anywhere in you app you can now write:

```
MyClass.MY_URL
```

To access the value

Comment: Yes, I found that answer too actually am getting undefined url because of i getting the url from the attribute (which i created manually) of <app-root> , thats why after the Web cam component , the ngOnInit of appcomponent cant access the <app-root> so i declare the url as seperate global.ts file , anyway thanks !